# Как построить запрос с 3 условиями?

Tags: laravel

Если id нет в get-параметре (строка) или в сессии (массив), то выводим по популярности все цвета, которые есть в наличии. Если в get-параметре есть id, то этот цвет должен быть первым. Если в get-параметре есть id и в сессии есть масса id, то первый должен быть цвет по get-параметру, потом цвета из массива сессии и только потом все остальные цвета. При этом, все цвета должны сортироваться по популярности и быть в наличии.

Сейчас у меня проверяется только наличие get-параметра.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $colors_ids = $request->session()->get('colors_ids');

    $this->validate($request, [
        'color' => 'numeric',
    ]);

    $colors = Color::where([['in_stock', '=', '1']])
                   ->orderByRaw(sprintf("CASE id WHEN %d THEN 1 ELSE 2 END", $request->get('color')))
                   ->orderBy("popularity", "desc")
                   ->get();

    return view('color.index', compact('colors'));
}
```

**UPDATE**

В любом из сценариев выводить нужно все цвета которые есть в наличии. Просто если в url есть get-параметр, то этот цвет должен быть самым первым, не зависимо от его популярности. Потом должны быть цвета, индикаторы которых мы берем из сессии и эти цвета должны быть отсортированы по популярности и быть в наличии. И только потом все остальные цвета которые есть в наличии отсортированы по популярности.

Если у нас есть get-параметр:

1. Цвет id которого мы взяли с get-параметра. Он должен быть в наличии.
2. Остальные цвета которые есть в наличии. Сортируем по популярности.

Если у нас есть только список ids из сессии:

1. Цвета, id которых мы взяли из сессии. Сортируем по популярности. Должны быть в наличии.
2. Остальные цвета которые есть в наличии. Сортируем по популярности.

Если у нас есть get-параметр и список ids из сессии:

1. Цвет id которого мы взяли с get-параметра. Он должен быть в наличии.
2. Цвета, id которых мы взяли из сессии. Сортируем по популярности. Должны быть в наличии.
3. Остальные цвета которые есть в наличии. Сортируем по популярности.

Если в сессии пусто и url не имеет get-параметра.

1. Все цвета которые есть в наличии. Сортируем по популярности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала вытаскиваете все имеющиеся в наличии цвета из базы, затем сортируете:

```
$requestedColorId = (int)$request->get('color') ?: 0;
$savedColorIds = $request->session()->get('colors_ids') ?: [];
$colors = PointAction::query()
    ->where('in_stock', '=', '1')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function ($product) use ($requestedColorId, $savedColorIds) {
        return [$product->id === $requestedColorId, in_array($product->id, $savedColorIds), $product->popularity];
    }, SORT_REGULAR, true);
```